# group panel with a border title in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create similar to the example panel shown in bootstrap documentation(see link below) but with the content(which is string 'Example' in this context) shown in the border of the panel instead of inside of the panel.

For example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

in the above link, Example is inside the group border panel. Instead of that I would like to have the 'Example' string in the panel border itself.
Like

-------Example---------------------------

Bonus would be if I can make it a button which would collapse the content. But even just text would do for me.

Thx for any help.

Comment: Any luck with a solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to do it yet. I will post it here if I find something.